# Encryption and Decryption of Alpahabets to Integers

Tags: linear-transformations, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

I'll explain my case with an example. Say, I've 2 words,

1. FOOTBALL
2. FOOD

Let f(FOOTBALL) = 845614,

f(FOOD)     = 74312

and f(FO)       = 132

Is there any method to get
f'(845614, 2) = 132 and f'(74312,2) = 132

Comment: what hypotesys do you have on $f$?

Comment: f is just a function to transform alphabet to numeric. The function f is not defined , it can be any set of operations. The integer values are example not the real values.

Comment: In general you can do nothing: an example is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: Conversion of Numeric to Corresponding Alphabets is Possible. 845614 <-> FOOTBALL. But is there any way to get first n letters of actual word if i give any parameters to the decryption function. i.e  f'(845614,2) - >FO,  f'(845614,3) - >FOO,

Comment: so you have a function $f$ determined by the values $f(A), \ldots, f(Z)$?

Comment: The function should be made so that it satisfies the above conditions

Comment: if you consider an arbitrary injective function $f: \text{"dictionary"} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ you can do nothing (matematically) because the values are independent